# NodeJS - TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, callback

I want to close my session after the loading is complete. I tried to normally put session.close() so i get TypeError - Write after end . And then i try to input a callback but i get callback is not a function error .

**app.js**

```
      var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://" + neo4jIP + ":" + neo4jPort, 
       neo4j.auth.basic( login, password ));

     var session = driver.session();

      allQueries = [cyphers]; // ***************** 

      var queries = [];

     var cypherStringified = JSON.stringify(cyphers);
     var cypherJSONLength = cyphers.length;


     Promise.all(queries)
        .then(function (results,callback) {
            results.forEach(function (result) {

            })
            console.log("Completed LOADING");

            // session.close();  // Typeerror -Write after end .


                      callback( session.close());



            deferred.resolve({ "resolve": "Done" });
            return deferred.promise;

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("inside catch 1= " , err);

        })

       }
```

**Error -**

```
 inside catch 1=  TypeError: callback is not a function
 at /home/dell/Downloads/api-mine-wsdlaws-controller.js:483:27
 at <anonymous>
 at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

Comment: `.then()` will not have the second parameter `callback` so callback is undefined., simply call the `return session.close()` or use it in the finally block

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.all(iterable).then(function(values) {
     //it returns values
     console.log(values);
});
```

You are using a `callback` , which isnt available and to the function and hence throwing error.

The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

> Read more about `Promise.all` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thanks manish. But then now how do i close the session. Because Promise is asynchronous and callback is synchronous. And i want to close the session with session.close(). Please help here

Comment: when exactly do you want to close the session . You can directly  close it in the `then()` function directly. as it will only execute after resolving all the promises.

Comment: But then i get write after end error. But i am not sure it is because of that session.close() inside .then that i am getting this error

Comment: you can return a `promise` object for the whole function and resolve inside `then()`.

Comment: Your main question is resolved with the description i provided . I would suggest to edit the question apply the changes and post either new or updated question. It would be easier to resolve that way.